# The Biggest Loser

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> I'm shiny.
>
> Yikes, I'm starting to burn!
>
> But I'm very careful.
>
> I'm all coiled up!
>
> I'm part of a plant now.
>
> Now I'm all stuck up.
>
> But I'm getting fat.
>
> Now I'm just a number,
>
> And now I'm just me

What on earth is going? Why am I changing so much?

Comment: I'm curious about the title: is this known to be the "biggest" example of its kind in the English lexicon?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm not sure, I was just trying to use a title that was both recognizable and a good clue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Take a letter from the word for each step, as per the title (The Biggest **Loser**)

I'm shiny

> Sparkling

Yikes, I'm starting to burn!

> Sparking (-l)

But I'm very careful.

> Sparing (-k)

I'm all coiled up!

> Spring (-a)

I'm part of a plant now.

> Sprig (-n)

Now I'm all stuck up.

> Prig (-s)

But I'm getting fat.

> Pig (-r)

Now I'm a number,

> Pi (-g)

And now I'm just me

> I (-p)

Comment: Good work. Will accept in 2 minutes. Would you mind adding a spoiler at the beginning? Thanks

Comment: Done. Good puzzle!

Comment: But why did you start from Sparkling? Is that the only word that fits all the pieces ?

Comment: I started by thinking about synonyms for "shiny" that were enough letters. After I saw that I could go from sparkling to sparking, I knew I was on the right path